# Change class name of list element based on incremental props value - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a progress step component which receives the number of steps (as a number) as props from the parent component.

My steps (think of a progress bar) component is structured like this:

```
    <div className="steps-wizard row">
      <div className="wizard ">
        <ul className="nobull progressbar">
          <li className="complete"></li>
          <li className="inactive"></li>
          <li className="inactive"></li>
          <li className="inactive"></li>
          <li className="inactive"></li>
          <li className="inactive"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="wizard steps">
        <ul className="nobull progressbar">
          <li>Step 1</li>
          <li>Step 2</li>
          <li>Step 3</li>
          <li>Step 4</li>
          <li>Step 5</li>
          <li>Step 6</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="wizard title">
        <ul className="nobull progressbar">
          <li>Intro</li>
          <li>Something new</li>
          <li>Overlay</li>
          <li>Pizza Menu</li>
          <li>Work Opportunities</li>
          <li>Final Summary</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The number of steps is incremented by clicking a button, you can also click a button to reduce the number of steps. So you start from `0` and go up to `5`.

**My question is:**

How do I change the `className=inactive` to `className=complete` based on the incremented step? For example, if the value of `this.props.currentStep` is `3`, my `nobull progressbar` should look like this:

```
    <ul className="nobull progressbar">
      <li className="complete"></li>
      <li className="complete"></li>
      <li className="complete"></li>
      <li className="complete"></li>
      <li className="inactive"></li>
      <li className="inactive"></li>
    </ul>
```

and if I decide to reduce the value of `currentSteps`, the amount of list elements with `className` complete will change accordingly.

What I've tried so far:

I've tried creating a state variable called `stepClass` and try to set it to `complete` based on the `this.props.currentSteps` value. Sadly the code below doesn't work.

```
this.state = {
  stepClass:'inactive'
}

 switch(currentStep) {
  case 1:
    this.setState({stepClass:'complete};
  case 2:
    this.setState({stepClass:'complete};
  case 3:
    this.setState({stepClass:'complete};
  case 4:
    this.setState({stepClass:'complete};
  case 5:
    this.setState({stepClass:'complete};
  default:
    this.setState({stepClass:'complete};
}
```

Comment: Hey, you can simply compare the value of **currentStep** with the **index** of the steps. If the **index** is less than **currentStep** then the class would be **complete** or else **inactive**.

Comment: Can you post the jsx you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this approach you have to know maximum amount of steps, it can be done like that:

```
class Stepper {
    renderSteps() {
        const { max, currentStep } = this.props
        return [...Array(max)].map((_, i) => (
            <li className={i <= currentStep ? 'completed' : 'inprogress'}></li>
        ))
    }

     render() {
         return (
            <ul>
                {this.renderSteps()}
            </ul>
         )
     }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: can I just ask you what exactly does `(_, i)` do? You are trying to compare `i` to the current step and based on that add the class `complete` but I'm not sure what the underscore is exactly. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: It's just a small convention to mark the first parameter as "unused", it just makes code a bit more readable, which's always nice :)